# X server hang for a couple minites and can't open display errors

Tags: linux, ssh, x11

I want to run a GUI application, like xclock, on a remote Linux system and view it on a local Windows 10 system.

After a few minutes of hanging, it displays an error message:
**Error: Can't open display: <win_ip_or_localhost>:0.0.**

I configured the situation as follows:
X11 server was successfully installed on windows using [***vcxsrv***](https://sourceforge.net/projects/vcxsrv/) software. The default `Display number` is set to `0.0`, which is always the same as the environment variable `DISPLAY=<win_ip_or_localhot>:0.0` on linux. The rest of the ***vcxsrv*** configuration remains the same. And the `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` variable in linux is set as follows (the default is the following):

```bash
#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
X11Forwarding yes
```

The variables in the "/etc/ssh/ssh_config" file are set as follows:

```bash
ForwardAgent yes
ForwardX11 yes
ForwardX11Trusted yes
```

I then saved the above file and exited.

In linux terminal, I run `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-core`, and I get the following output:

```
ii xserver-xorg-core 2:1.20.13-1ubuntu1~20.04.3 amd64 Xorg X server - core server
```

Finally, I logged into the linux server via `ssh -XY <host>@<remote_linux_ip>` with X11 forwarding on my local computer [***git-bash***](https://gitforwindows.org/), then ran `xclock` and it hung for a few minutes with no response, followed by the above error.

### My Attempts

---

I have tried hard to resolve this by trying:

- Change the port number, change the environment "DISPLAY" value in "~/.bashrc" in linux, `export DISPLAY="<my_win_ip>:13.0"`. The vcxsrv software also changes the "Display number" to the same 13.0 to accept client requests. Or modify it to `export DISPLAY="localhost:13.0"`, at this time no hang wait directly reported the above error.
- add ssh local port mapping, execute `ssh -XYL <my_win_ip>:6000:<remote_linux_ip>:6000 <host>@<remote_linux_ip>` on `git-bash` on windows, where the port number 6000 is the corresponding The "Display number" is an inherent offset of 0. Similarly, other numbers should be added as offsets.
- close the firewall, Linux and windows firewall have been determined to close, and then carry out the above method steps.

---

In addition, I also tried the [`mobaXterm`](https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/) terminal tool to try, because it comes with X-Server, no need to install vcxsrv software or Xming, etc. When using `mobaXterm`, I quit the vcxsrv software beforehand, the displayed port number is the same as the server, but after logging into the linux server, it still hangs for some time. The same error is then reported.

Your answer will be appreciated.

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to set DISPLAY manually on the remote server. If ssh successfully forwards X, then DISPLAY should already be set to the correct value. If it's not set, then forwarding through ssh isn't going to work. If it _is_ set and you overwrite it, you're probably replacing the correct value with an incorrect value.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @Kenster, I was able to log in to the remote Linux server successfully via `ssh -X`, `DISPLAY` still needs to be set manually by me as it doesn't change automatically, I also tried multiple values, if the values don't match it will report an error immediately, if it matches successfully it will hang for a while before reporting the error.

Comment: Why do you feel it's necessary to set DISPLAY manually on the remote system? If you don't set it to something, what (if anything) is it set to by default?

Comment: If I don't set DISPLAY manually and then log in to the linux remote terminal with ` ssh -X ` on git-bash, `echo $DISPLAY` shows empty, but logging in with `ssh -Y`, `echo $DISPLAY` shows `localhost:12.0`, then followed by executing `xclock`, which immediately shows **_Could not find ':' in DISPLAY: needs-to-be-defined 
Error: Can't open display: localhost:12.0_** error is reported.

Comment: Another strange thing is that when I logged into the Linux remote server terminal with `Mobaxterm` alone, the DISPLAY value was also "localhost:12.0", and then I executed `xclock`, the desired window flickered and then the output was **_Warning: locale not supported by Xlib, locale set to C supported by Xlib, locale set to C
Warning: X locale modifiers not supported, using default
Warning: Unable to load any usable fontset
_**, the terminal keeps hanging.
The terminal hangs when trying other GUI applications, but does not output any information.